# Javascript navigation with keyboard for website - help needed

Tags: css, keyboard, navigation, keydown

i am trying to create a website navigation using keyboard only.
I searched the web an found some sample an i made little progress.

No i reached my limit, due knowledge. I would like to get the value of the selected li/href so i can open that link with enter.
Here is my codesample so far.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Navigation</title>
  <style>
    li.selected {
      background: yellow
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href="http://www.bing.de">First Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.google.de">Second Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">Third Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 40) { //40=Pfeil nach unten
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.next();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 38) { //40=Pfeil nach oben
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.prev();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 13) { //13=Enter
        //missing code, how to open the selected href link from above
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am looking forward to get some tips.

Thanks, AxLED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the attr method on the selected list item's anchor. 

[Click here](https://codepen.io/csgokul/pen/eMPzMw) **for  a pen to help you out**

```js
    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 40) { //40=Pfeil nach unten
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.next();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 38) { //40=Pfeil nach oben
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.prev();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 13) { 
        window.location.href = $('.selected a').attr('href');
        
      }

      

      
      
      
    });
```

```css
   li.selected {
      background: yellow
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="linksList">
    <li><a id="link1" href="https://www.bing.de">First Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://www.bing.de">Second Link</a></li>
    <li> <a  href="https://www.bing.de">Third Link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to actually add event for <kbd>Enter</kbd>, But here you go:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Navigation</title>
  <style>
    li.selected {
      background: yellow
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: blue
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a id="link1" href="http://www.bing.de">Bing Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.google.de">google Link</a></li>
    <li> <a href="http://www.duckduckgo.com">Duck Duck Link</a></li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    var li = $('li');
    var liSelected;
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 40) { //40=Pfeil nach unten
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.next();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.eq(0).addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 38) { //40=Pfeil nach oben
        if (liSelected) {
          liSelected.removeClass('selected');
          next = liSelected.prev();
          if (next.length > 0) {
            liSelected = next.addClass('selected');
          } else {
            liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
          }
        } else {
          liSelected = li.last().addClass('selected');
        }
      } else if (e.which === 13) { //13=Enter
         window.open(liSelected.find("a").attr('href'));
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
//missing code, how to open the selected href link from above
liSelected.find("a")[0].click();
```

should do the job. `liSelected` is the correct list node; the clickable anchor tag is a child of that `liSelected` node which can be found with [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/).

Note that `liSelected` might be undefined if an arrow key hasn't been pressed, so you'll want to add a check for that to your conditional (e.g. `else if(e.which === 13 && liSelected)`).